# Can fail take non-String argument?

Tags: haskell

I was trying to write [some `EitherT` monad transformer, as suggested from real world haskell chapter 18](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monad-transformers.html#x_fu).

```
newtype EitherT e m a = EitherT {
    runEitherT :: m (Either e a) 
}
```

my `EitherT` will have `Left error` and `Right result` for its `Either` type, and will bind all computation that yields `Right` values while stopping at `left` values, keeping them as error.

my code is below(sorry for the imperative style):

```
bindET :: (Monad m) => (EitherT e m a) -> (a -> EitherT e m b) -> (EitherT e m b)
x `bindET` f = EitherT $ do
    mx <- runEitherT x
    case mx of
        Right success -> runEitherT (f success)
        Left error -> return (Left error)


instance (Monad m) => Monad (EitherT e m) where
    return a = EitherT $ return (Right a)
    (>>=) = bindET
    fail e = EitherT $ return (Left e)
```

I thought writing `Monad` instances for `EitherT` transformer was quite simple, however I get this cryptic error message when I load the code into ghci:

```
EitherT.hs:30:18:
    Could not deduce (e ~ [Char])
    from the context (Monad m)
      bound by the instance declaration at EitherT.hs:27:10-41
      `e' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the instance declaration at EitherT.hs:27:10
    Expected type: EitherT e m a
      Actual type: EitherT String m a
    In the expression: EitherT $ return (Left e)
    In an equation for `fail': fail e = EitherT $ return (Left e)
    In the instance declaration for `Monad (EitherT e m)'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

it seems `fail` function is fixed to take `String` as an argument - well, if that's the case then my `EitherT e m a` will be `EitherT String m a` and all the `Left` values will be `Left String`. but I want `EitherT` monad to take any types of value as `Left` to indicate errors in computation. How can I achieve that?

Comment: This is indeed a problem, and has historically led to a bit of fragmentation. [`EitherT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/either-4.4.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Either.html#t:EitherT), [`ErrorT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Error.html#t:ErrorT), and [`ExceptT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html#t:ExceptT) all represent subtly different points in the space of solutions that you might want to explore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`EitherT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/either-4.4.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Either.html) is also an instance of [`MonadError`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Error-Class.html#t:MonadError), giving you `throwError :: e -> EitherT e m a`. If you are implementing your own `EitherT` for educational reasons, you can look up `MonadError` at the link above and figure out how to make your own `ErrorT` type also an instance of that.

`fail` is generally considered a poor interface, because a, it is tied to `String` as you noticed and b, because it is in `Monad`, forcing monads to implement it even when it doesn't make sense.

Comment: so I should introduce some error-reporting protocol (such as `throwError` in case of `mtl`)  for errors, and leave `fail = error` (the default implementation in haskell)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `fail` in that way, you can define the monad as `EitherT String m`:

```
instance (Monad m) => Monad (EitherT String m) where
    -- ...
```

This is not as useless as it looks, since errors are usually strings anyway.

The benefit of doing it this way is that you can handle pattern match failures. This could be handy if you want to (for example) call an action that needs to return `Just`

```
do
    Just a <- lift getTheThing
    lift (print a)
```

The downside is you get a less-than-useful error message `"pattern match failure in ..."` rather than something like `"couldn't get the thing, try restarting the server"`.

If you just want to have something to call manually on failure though, use `throwError` like Cactus suggests.